# Trying to access bean created in servlet via JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to access a bean I create in a servlet from a JSP.
In my servlet `BlogController.java` I instantiate the bean like this

```
    BlogList bloglist = new BlogList();
    if (bloglist.getSize()<1) {
        bloglist.addDummies();
        //Now the size of the bloglist is 10
    }
```

Then, still in this servlet I call the jsp like

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Blog7.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

and inside the JSP I am trying to use the bean like

```
<jsp:useBean id="bloglist" type="ub7.BlogList" scope="session"/>
```

but the size of `bloglist` is 0 here, why?

Comment: You are creating a new bean in jsp, @Saphire

Comment: Try my answer below and let me know if that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add the bean into the session at the servlet itself:

**in servlet**

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("bloglist", bloglist);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Blog7.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**in jsp**

```
Blog List count: ${sessionScope.bloglist.size()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Blog7.jsp");
request.setAttribute("bloglist", bloglist); // Will be available as ${bloglist} in JSP
rd.forward(request, response);
```

and in JSP :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
....
<table>
<c:forEach items="${bloglist}" var="blog">
    <tr>
        <td>${blog.name}</td>            
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `<jsp:useBean>` defines `scope="session"`, your servlet should do (*before* calling the `RequestDispatcher`):

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("bloglist", bloglist);
```